# How do I update a JavaScript class object that is an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, class, oop

I am new to object-oriented programming and I have been given a problem to solve where I need to create a JavaScript class with attributes and functions. One of the attributes is an array of strings that stores multiple strings. The object instantiation is as follows:

```
let person = new Person('Bob', 30, 'Male', ['hunting', 'the gym', 'photography']);
```

The output should be:
Hello, my name is Bob, my gender is male and I am 30 years old. My interests are hunting, the gym and photography.

Here is what I have done so far:

```
class Person
{
    static name;
    static age;
    static gender;
    static interests = [];

    constructor(name, age, gender)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.interests = addInterests();
    }
    hello(){
        return "Hello, my name is " + this.name + " my gender is " + this.gender + " and I am " + this.age + " years old. My interests are " + this.interests + " .";
    }
    addInterests()
    {
        for(let i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++)
        {
            interests.push(arguments[i]);
        }
    }
}

let person = new Person('Ryan', 30, 'male',['being a hardarse', 'agile', 'ssd hard drives']);
let greeting = person.hello();
console.log(greeting);
```

I understand how to update the other attributes but I'm stuck on how to update the array attribute. Please help.

Comment: _"`arguments` is an Array-like object accessible inside functions that contains the values of the arguments **passed to that function**."_

Comment: You're not using `arguments` as an array, since you're passing an array as an argument. If you want to use `arguments` like that, call `Person` like `let person = new Person('Bob', 30, 'Male', 'hunting', 'the gym', 'photography');` and only take the fourth argument onwards. Of course, you should research [rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) to make it easier.

Comment: @HereticMonkey it's not even a rest argument - it's just a normal one. `constructor(name, age, gender)` -> `constructor(name, age, gender, interests)` and then `this.interests = addInterests();` -> `this.interests = interestes;`

Comment: @VLAZ As I'm well aware. I said the OP should research rest parameters to make the process easier, if the example constructor is the preferred method of construction.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just treat the array as a regular argument?

```
class Person
{
    static name;
    static age;
    static gender;
    static interests = [];

    constructor(name, age, gender, interests)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.interests = interests;
    }
    hello(){
       return "Hello, my name is " + this.name + " my gender is " + this.gender + " and I am " + this.age + " years old. My interests are " + this.interests
    }
}

let person = new Person('Ryan', 30, 'male',['being a hardarse', 'agile', 'ssd hard drives']);
let greeting = person.hello();
console.log(greeting)
```